# Поставить EXE файл в автозагрузку

Tags: c, exe, автозагрузка

Есть exe файл написанный на языке C, я хочу, чтобы при запуске данного файла, он сразу копировал себя в автозагрузку. Как я могу это сделать

Comment: Вызвать соответствующие функции WinAPI, но любой антивирусник сразу заорёт.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Можно подробнее

Comment: Автозагрузок гораздо больше одной. Автозагрузка станции/ОС или профиля? Если профиля - любого, определённых или текущего? А что насчёт блокировки и выхода из неё? А как насчёт гибернации? Мало хотеть - надо ещё хорошо понять, что же ты на самом деле хочешь.